# parsing nested json issue

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am new here and I am parsing json which is array in side array so I can't understand how get inside array from json let me show you my json.

**JSON**

```
{
    "subject_list" =     (
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 4;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 17;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1530600693.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = " 01. Measurement";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 23;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1451930609.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 24;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1884777188.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 25;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1518702048.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 4;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = Physics;
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 8;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 26;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1437196139.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = " 1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 8;
                },
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 27;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1903171865.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 8;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = Chemistry;
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 9;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 31;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1319333294.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 9;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = Testing;
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 10;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 28;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1373218664.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 10;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = "Test Subject";
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 11;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 29;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/246189282.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 11;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = "Test Subject 1";
        },
                {
            "con_id" = 2;
            "level_id" = 1;
            "sub_id" = 12;
            "sub_list" =             (
                                {
                    "ch_id" = 30;
                    "ch_image" = "http://mobileapp.xmeducation.com/upload/1342731807.jpg";
                    "ch_name" = "1. Test Chapter";
                    "con_id" = 2;
                    "level_id" = 1;
                    "sub_id" = 12;
                }
            );
            "sub_name" = "Test Subject 2";
        }
    );
```

this is my JSON and I want `sub_list` array from `subject_list` I have done some code let me show you.

**CODE**

```
func callSubChapAPI(){
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let studentlvl = "student_lvl"
        let student_lvl = preferences.object(forKey: studentlvl) as! String
        print(student_lvl)
        let params = ["level_id": student_lvl]
        Alamofire.request(subListWithChapter, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let data):
                print(data)

                let json  = JSON(data)
                print(json)
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let subjects = try decoder.decode(SubjectResponse.self, from: data as! Data)
                    print(subjects)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            case.failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        })
    }
```

here is my struct:

```
struct sub_list {
    let ch_id : Int
    let ch_image: String
    let ch_name: String
    let con_id: String
    let level_id: String
    let sub_id: String
}
```

Please see my code and json format please tell me how to get `sub_list` array from json please hell me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `subject_list` is also an `array` so you need to iterate that as well.

```
let data = json["subject_list"]
print(data)
data.array?.forEach({ (subject) in
     subject["sub_list"].array?.forEach({ (chapList) in
           let chapter = sub_list(ch_id: chapList["ch_id"].intValue, ch_image: chapList["ch_image"].stringValue, ch_name: chapList["ch_name"].stringValue, con_id: chapList["con_id"].stringValue, level_id: chapList["level_id"].stringValue, sub_id: chapList["sub_id"].stringValue)
           print(chapter)
           self.chapListData.append(chapter)
     })
})

self.collView.reloadData()
```

---

**Recommendation**

It's not worth adding any dependency for `json` parsing when you already have Apple provided `Codable`. It will reduce much of your boilerplate code added because of `SwiftyJSON`.

Below is a complete example for your current api,

```
struct SubjectResponse: Decodable {
    let subjectList: [Subject]
}

struct Subject: Decodable {
    let subList: [Chapter]
}

struct Chapter: Decodable {
    let chId : Int
    let chImage: String
    let chName: String
    let conId: Int
    let levelId: Int
    let subId: Int
}

Alamofire.request(subListWithChapter, method: .post, parameters: params).responseData() { (response) in
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let data):
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let subjects = try decoder.decode(SubjectResponse.self, from: data)
            print(subjects)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: when i put your code so for data it giving suggestion like this Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Data' and when i insert as! its giving me crash Data

Comment: Error is like :  Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x1c6c8dcc0) to 'NSData' (0x1c6c8ddd8).
2018-12-18 12:22:13.912859+0530 XMEducation[5496:1296891] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI' (0x1c6c8dcc0) to 'NSData' (0x1c6c8ddd8).

Comment: You must be using `.responseJSON` while you have to use `responseData()`. Copy the complete example.

Comment: i  copied but still its giving me issue

Comment: You are using wrong method here `Alamofire.request(subListWithChapter, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON`. Just copy the whole example i provided above.

Comment: Yes its working now please help me last that how to set image url in imageview 
 which in side collection view from response please

Comment: please help me how to populate image from SubjectResponse to Collectionview

Comment: That is a different question. But its has already been asked multiple time. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift) question and in my opinion you should use `Jack` or `Leo Dabus` answers that has extensions on `UIImageView`.

Comment: Please don't ask different questions here. You can post as separate questions. Also if the above answer helped, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Yes but i want to ask is that how can i get only image url from whole data

Comment: You can get all the urls as this `let urls = subjects.subjectList.map({ $0.subList.map({ $0.chImage}) }).reduce([], +)`